# How to show loading blocker view in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

I want to show loading blocker view while any HTTP request is going to server or when I am doing any async operations.

The main goal is sometimes we want to stop end user interaction with App UI until the operation complete.

> In the Android world I would call the ProgressDialog, which causes the
>   screen to dim and the phone-specific spinner animation and whatever
>   message I want in the middle of the screen.

I know in windows phone we have option to indicate process in System tray

```
            ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator
            {
                IsVisible = true,
                IsIndeterminate = true,
                Text = "Connecting to server..." //TODO:Locale
            };
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progress);
```

But, I want to blocker UI interaction by adding view and my own loader animation in that view.

Can we call same view from whole application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a grid that cover all the page and control its Visibility by a property

```
<Grid  Visibility="{Binding Path=YourGrid.LoadingVisibility,Source={StaticResource Locator}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default,Mode=TwoWay}"   x:Name="OverlayGrid" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource PortraitGridStyle}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="White" Opacity="0.4"></Border>
        <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="400" Height="10" />
    </Grid>
```

This sample have the default animation in the Windows phone where 5 dots float around using progressbar control

Comment: Thanks for reply - I am using http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/ Progress Overlay. It works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link, will be helpful in the future